# deployment of golang project with yaml file

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, minikube

i have a shopping card app with server and client side and i want to deploy it using Minikube and Kubernetes
should we create two Yaml files for the server and the client or not ?
any ideas guys on how to create the Yaml files.

Answer (score 1):

one for server and one for client

simple path

```
k8s
   -values_production.yaml for production server
   -value_staging.yaml for staging server
```

thats all

in yaml files you should store enviroment variables and parse them by prefixes it's most simple way

Comment: and how can i specify the yaml file for the client and the server ?

Comment: one folder with k8s on client and one folder on server 
deploy them not together

Comment: I am new in deployment and using yaml... how to create it ?

Comment: @hajji just read the documents https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/